# Discrete line inside a 3D matrix

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, procedural-generation, unityscript

First of all a little premise: I'm following [this tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RiGikVLS3c) for procedural 2d cave generation in unity using cellular automata and I'm extending it in order to make caves in all three dimensions. With this approach, caves are based on a 3d matrix where if a cell value is 1 it is a wall and if 0 it is an empty space.
The "rooms" created, after being logically connected, need to be "physically" connected by making a path of zeros in the 3d matrix and the tutorial explains how to do this in 2d.

Can you, please, suggest me the approach on how to draw a discrete line (of zeros in this case), in a 3d matrix, that goes from point A to point B?

I'll attach a screen of a map example where rooms are drawn with cubes and red lines are the logical connections.

[image: Screenshot of a generated cave]

Comment: Bresenham's line drawing algorithm, originally in 2D, has been revised in many places with a 3D version.

Comment: I would bet that a DDA line algorithm could also work in 3D.

Comment: Bresenham is more efficient that DDA.